# "-bash: 1: command not found" when evaluating >2&1

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to get the return value from `cpp` according to [How to invert a count returned from grep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238857). I've got a script failing with the message ***`-bash: 1: command not found`***.

Here's the reduced test case:

```
$ echo `cpp -dM -fsanitize=undefined < /dev/null > /dev/null >2&1`
-bash: 1: command not found
```

Why is Bash trying to execute `1` as a command, and how do I clear the error?

Comment: You probably meant `2>&1` rather than `>2&1`

Comment: @steeldriver - damn, you're right... Sorry about the extra noise, everyone. Do you want to answer and get the points? Or do you want me to delete the question?

Comment: BTW, it's better to use `$(cmd)` than to put `cmd` in backticks. The `$(cmd)` form is easier to read, and can be nested. Also, it's not easy to put backticks in Stack Exchange comments. :) Also, doing `echo $(cmd)` (or the equivalent with backticks) is kinda pointless. Just do `cmd`.

Comment: @PM2Ring - thanks, I was not aware of that. I don't recall when I learned to use the back ticks, so I can't offer more information. I'm a C/C++ guy, and not a shell scripter (as you can probably tell :)

Comment: No worries. The backticks / `$(cmd)` construction is when you want to capture the output of `cmd` so it can be put into a variable, or passed to another command. But if you just want to see the output in the terminal you should run `cmd` directly. And if you want to get the return code from the previous command it's in the `$?` special variable.

Comment: Backticks mess up quoting (in your script, not just on this web site).  Use `$(cmd)` instead.  Backticks are old and everyone used to use them back in the primitive cave-hacker days with dinosaurs and sabertooths and such.  Now we realise the problems, know better and use `$()` instead.

Comment: I agree `$()` is better in many ways.  However, the last time I used automake, they recommended backticks for maximum portability.  So this rule of thumb is not universal.

Comment: Copy your line into shellcheck.net, press the arrow and click on 'name syntax'. If you still have any confusions,  try [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cpp%20-dM%20-fsanitize=undefined%20%3C%20/dev/null%20%3E%20/dev/null%20%3E2&1) too. Many shell questions don't actually need human to answer.

Comment: @RobertL I happen to read the [Portable Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Portable-Shell.html) things earlier today (ah, yesterday?) too. The cruelty of the messy Unix shell world freaks me up. However, I'd still stick to POSIX to make my life easier, since at least I've got something to blame for…

Answer (score 4):

As @steeldriver pointed out, the problem is because of the mis-constructed io redirection.  Here's why:

```
    cpp  > 2   &   1
```

The cpp process gets put in the background with output redirected to a file named "2", the ampersand is also a command separator like the semi-colon, so the next command in line is "1", which the shell cannot find.